# Avoid caching image caching

Tags: magento2, javascript, product-images, ajax, full-page-cache

is there a way to add versioning for the product image? 
I'm having trouble with image caching in the site, i can't control user browser for caching but maybe i can add a versioning for my images when they are updated
something like `images.jpg?1234`

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea. If you add the file's modification time, it will be cached by the browser until you upload a new file.

Example:

```
echo('<img  src="image.png?' . filemtime('image.png') . '" />');
```

See: http://php.net/filemtime

Comment: Hello Dbrekelmans, i want to be able to add this to magento, there  is a lot of example online that give you the option to have versioning or king trick the browser by showing different image name, my objective is to be able to add this to magento 2x